# Save email as html in apple mail

Tags: html, apple-mail

Is there an easy way to take an HTML email that is in AppleMail and save it out as an HTML file that can be used for email updates?

I know in Outlook you can save as html file but looking to do this on a mac with AppleMail.

I know i can view the raw source data but this doesnt provide me with the right information. THe HTML is all jumbled and not what i am looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.outlookimport.com/export-e-mails-from-apple-mail-and-import-to-ms-outlook/),
EML is the HTML format I think you are looking for.

Comment: Well i dont want to import it into Outlook, i want to use it as an html file. I dont have access to outlook on the mac.

Comment: EML is formatted the same as mht (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML). The link describes how to export it to EML wich is alomst the same as MHT, wich is a form of HTML. I took a few shortcuts, but I suggest to give it a try.

Comment: Yah it seems that i need to manually go into the funky eml file and clean it up, thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced the same issue and tried almost all the solutions but didn't work. So at the end I did following to get HTML

- Forward the email to gmail :)
- Open gmail on browser
- Inspect element to the outer most HTML element
- Copy HTML from inspector
- Create new file (using sublime or any other HTML editor) pasted code and save it as HTML file
- Got my desired HTML

:)

Answer (score 1):

In `mail.app` menu:

> Edit > Save as...

Format: `Raw Message Source`, this will save as `EML` (some form of html as mentioned by [Jasper Duizendstra's answer and comments](https://superuser.com/a/381042/55267)).

You can also use `Rich Text Format` (will save as `.rtf`). Then you can use GNU's [UnRTF](https://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/). `unrtf` can be installed with [brew](https://brew.sh/) like this:

```bash
brew install unrtf
```

Here's how you'd use it

```bash
unrtf --html input.rtf > output.html
```